# Is there a working Open source implementation of litecoin mining application for Linux without GUI

Tags: development, litecoin, scrypt

Is there a working Open source implementation of litecoin mining application for Linux flavours without GUIs (think debian, ubuntu server etc.)

I found a couple of implementations by developers but all of them are closed source.

Answer (score 2):

[cgminer](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer) should work, it is open source, cross platform miner for bitcoins and litecoins (--scrypt key  used for scrypt based coins like litecoin.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the litecoin.org client on github includes  litecoind which would be the non-GUI version.

https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/blob/master-0.8/INSTALL

https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/blob/master-0.8/doc/build-unix.md

Answer (score 0):

there are many, googling "litecoin mining software" will find you some.

I've used:
https://github.com/cbuchner1/CudaMiner
https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/